# How can get Screen dispositive width with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set screen dispositive width for a div using JS, using the following line:

```
var cont = document.getElementById("content");
cont.style.width = (screen.width * 0.93)+"px";
```

It sets a percentage width equals to the full width of the actual zoom, When use 100% of zoom. It returns 1440, but when use 80% and reload, width increase to 1800.

I need get Screen size of dispositive, independently what zoom is using on.
[image]

Or I should to use a zoom listener?

Comment: ff and ie seem to do this but not chrome, which makes things more interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [window.devicePixelRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) as a modifier (at least sometimes)* **

```
console.log(window.devicePixelRatio * screen.width)
```

*There is a problem here in how the browser interprets the screen width when zoomed. I ran a quick test with FF, IE and Chrome and while FF and IE are giving the result you describe, Chrome always displays the same width... which means this doesn't work in Chrome (at least).

**I also have no idea of the browser compatibility, it is in working draft status. It seemed to work on the modern browsers I tested at least.

Comment: In Firefox, I get results like `1919.9999313354492` instead of 1920 when I'm zoomed in. You'll probably want to use Math.round() to account for the floating point imprecision.

Answer (score -1):

I think this can help you

```
for (var i = 100; !window.matchMedia('(max-device-width: ' + i + 'px)').matches; i++) {}
var deviceWidth = i;
console.log(deviceWidth);
```

Comment: "i" never assigns the value to deviceWidth because it's out of block

Comment: @FabioGonzaga did you debug the code? it does actually run yes, but it gives the same incorrect result as the code in the question

Comment: Ok, here it worked well, if the real device width you want it.

Comment: I've tested and same :(

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for availHeight and availWidth.

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qr8w2eyn/

Comment: it still increase

Comment: this does the same thing

Comment: @Asahi Sara - Oh sorry, it worked in Chrome. But I guess Firefox and IE are the ones with the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use window.outerWidth instead of your code.